# Can't set Gnome terminal theme

Tags: themes, gnome-terminal, ubuntu-gnome

Anytime I change the gnome shell/ terminal theme nothing happens it stays the same dull color schemes. Am i missing some setting here I have dash to panel installed.

[image]

[image: Screenfetch]

[image: added image]

Comment: Add a screenshot of your GNOME Terminal profile preferences' colours tab, please.

Comment: Is that under tweak tools or in terminal?

Comment: @muru personally I just assumed that the box use colors from systems settings should be the fix to make them sync, it was unchecked i just checked it.

Comment: So your problem is solved?

Comment: Yes I guess I expected them to auto sync but it makes sense for there being an option to not have  them being​ the same thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: In that case, can you post that as an answer? The checkbox that you ticked, and the screenshot of it?

Comment: Its take care of @muru

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to have the "use colors from system theme" box checked as shown below.

[image]